# Custom website link to Dataverse without Power App

Tags: dataverse

How can I go about creating an https form and getting input from there into dataverse without having an app created on Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to create application user in Azure to use dataverse API

[Step by step to connect to D365 with a client_secret to use APIs](https://dynamics-chronicles.com/article/step-step-connect-d365-clientsecret-use-apis)

[This is one example of how to consue dataverse API using Application user in python](https://coderscollection.wordpress.com/2020/07/25/integrate-microsoft-dynamics-365-ce-with-python-3-6/)

There are numerous other example of consuming dataverse API, bascially you will need to authicate and get Token and then accees API